# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when loading image

Tags: java, android

when i try to scroll for more images from sd card it's showing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:601)
at net.altnetwork.accountability.helpers.ScreenshotLibrary$LibraryItem.getBitmap(ScreenshotLibrary.java:124)
 at net.altnetwork.accountability.helpers.ScreenshotLibrary$ItemGroup.getBitmaps(ScreenshotLibrary.java:102)
 at net.altnetwork.accountability.v2.GalleryAdapter.getView(GalleryAdapter.java:127)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)

at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)

at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1320)

at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)

at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3348)

at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)


at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)

at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)

at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)

at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)

at java.lang.refl
  Force finishing activity net.altnetwork.accountability/.activities.HomeActivity
```

this is class file ......

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnItemClickListener {

private Context mContext;
private int numcolumn;
private int NoOfListItem;
GridView grid;
int ListItemHeight;
private String[] header;
SharedPreferences groupbyPref;
private SharedPreferences GalleryPref;
ScreenshotLibrary myScreenshotLibrary = null;

public GalleryAdapter(Context gallery, int NumOfListItem, String[] str) {
    SharedPreferences ImageSizePref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(gallery);
    numcolumn = ImageSizePref.getInt("NoOfColumn", 5);
    GalleryPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(gallery);

    Editor edit = GalleryPref.edit();
    edit.putInt("NumOfListItem", NumOfListItem);
    edit.commit();

    this.header = str;
    this.mContext = gallery;

    this.ListItemHeight = GalleryPref.getInt("ListHeight", 1000);
    this.NoOfListItem = GalleryPref.getInt("NumOfListItem", 5);

    groupbyPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(gallery);

    String key = groupbyPref.getString("GroupKey", "DAY");

    if (key.equals("DAY")) {
        myScreenshotLibrary = ScreenshotLibrary.getInstance(gallery,
                ScreenshotLibrary.GroupingMethod.DAY);
        Bitmap[] item = myScreenshotLibrary.getGroup(1).getBitmaps();

    }
    if (key.equals("WEEK")) {
        myScreenshotLibrary = ScreenshotLibrary.getInstance(gallery,
                ScreenshotLibrary.GroupingMethod.WEEK);

    }
    if (key.equals("MONTH")) {
        myScreenshotLibrary = ScreenshotLibrary.getInstance(gallery,
                ScreenshotLibrary.GroupingMethod.MONTH);

    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NoOfListItem;

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public void setnumcol(int i) {
    grid.setNumColumns(i);
    grid.requestLayout();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int ListItemHeight(int length) {
    SharedPreferences ImageSizePref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    Log.i("listsize",
            "" + ((12 / numcolumn) + 1)
                    * ImageSizePref.getInt("ImageParm", 100));
    Log.i("listsizen", "" + ((12 / numcolumn) + 1));
    Log.i("listsizei", "" + 12 % 4);
    if (length % numcolumn == 0) {
        return ((length / numcolumn))
                * ImageSizePref.getInt("ImageParm", 100) + 55;
    } else {
        return ((length / numcolumn) + 1)
                * ImageSizePref.getInt("ImageParm", 100) + 55;
    }

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    View customRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    grid = (GridView) customRow.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    TextView txt = (TextView) customRow.findViewById(R.id.header);
    txt.setText(header[position]);
    Bitmap[] item = myScreenshotLibrary.getGroup(position).getBitmaps();
    grid.setAdapter(new gridadt(mContext, item));
    grid.setNumColumns(numcolumn);

    grid.requestLayout();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    grid.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    customRow
            .setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(
                    ListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ListItemHeight(item.length)));
    Log.i("itemHeight", "" + customRow.getLayoutParams().height);
    customRow.requestLayout();
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return customRow;
}

public class gridadt extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mcontext;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms;
    private int GroupCount;
    ScreenshotLibrary myScreenshotLibrary = null;
    private int count;
    Bitmap[] images;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public gridadt(Context adapter, Bitmap[] item) {
        // inflater = ((Activity) mcontext).getLayoutInflater();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) adapter
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.mcontext = adapter;
        this.images = item;
        this.count = item.length;
        SharedPreferences ImageSizePref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(adapter);

        int size = ImageSizePref.getInt("ImageParm", 100);
        parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        public ImageView image;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            /****** Inflate grid_item.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

            /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        ImageView image = holder.image;

        // image.setImageBitmap(images[position]);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
        image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        image.setLayoutParams(parms);
        return vi;
    }

}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

}
```

}

this is function use for getting image,,,,,,,,,,

```
public class LibraryItem{
    public Bitmap getBitmap() throws FileNotFoundException{
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.gallery_thumb_img1);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to wade through your code and see exactly where it's happening, but your issue is surely that you're getting references to too many images without making any of them available for garbage collection. Then when the android device no longer has enough memory to support all the images, you get an OOM exception.

In your Library adapter line 127, you call "getBitmaps", then you set that in a `new grdadt`. Make sure you entirely dereference that `new grdadt` at some point in your code (say when it scrolls out of view) and it should allow garbage collection to work properly.

Comment: can you help out me. to do that

Comment: You'll have to figure out how to do that yourself for the most part, but I'd certainly like to help. However, I don't know what the class `grdadt` is, which is am important piece of the puzzle.

Comment: thank you..so much for your help...gridadt class is adapter class and which is gridview and loaded images will be use in gridadt...

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

That block seems to be your problem to me, especially the following line:

```
Bitmap[] item = myScreenshotLibrary.getGroup(position).getBitmaps();
```

Seems like you are saving all the bitmaps every time you call that function, and it gets called a lot if I'm not mistaken.